# Generate multiple interfaces for one class/interface

Tags: reinforced-typings

Is there a way to generate multiple interfaces/classes for one class.

I'll have a SignalR hub class that looks like this:

```
[TsInterface]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetMessages() {...}

    public async Task EmitMessage(string msg) {...}
}
```

And this is what i want the output to be like:

```
interface ChatHub extends SignalR.Hub.Proxy {
    client: ChatHubClient;
    server: ChatHubServer;
}

interface ChatHubClient { // always empty. }

interface ChatHubServer {
    getMessages(): Promise<string[]>;
    emitMessage(msg: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using simple interface code generator:

```cs
using Reinforced.Typings.Ast;
using Reinforced.Typings.Ast.TypeNames;
using Reinforced.Typings.Generators;

class ClientAppender : InterfaceCodeGenerator
{
    public override RtInterface GenerateNode(Type element, RtInterface result, TypeResolver resolver)
    {

        var existing = base.GenerateNode(element, result, resolver);
        if (existing == null) return null;

        if (this.Context.Location.CurrentNamespace == null) return existing;
        RtInterface clientIFace = new RtInterface()
        {
            Name = new RtSimpleTypeName(string.Format("{0}Client", element.Name))
        };
        this.Context.Location.CurrentNamespace.CompilationUnits.Add(clientIFace);
        return existing;
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```cs
 builder.ExportAsInterface<ChatHub>()
            .WithPublicMethods()
            .WithPublicProperties()
            .WithCodeGenerator<ClientAppender>();
```

Sorry, I had no free time to answer your previous question.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. No worries about the previous question :)